# Monitoring React frontend application using Prometheus

Tags: javascript, reactjs, prometheus

Monitoring React frontend applications using [Prometheus](https://prometheus.io/).

I am monitoring my Node JS API calls by using https://www.npmjs.com/package/prom-client. How can I monitor code that is transferred to the browser i.e. the code inside bundle.js that has lots and lots of react code that gets executed in the browser?

Answer (score 0):

Prometheus is used for server side performance monitoring. For client-side React application profiling, I think Google Analytics may be a better tool.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30895222)